# convert any file to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, dll, com, pdf-generation

in my company we need a tool that convert any printable file to pdf.
until now we have used PDFCreator, our problem with it is that it is a external tool which uses COM, and its not very stable when using it on servers or multiple users. can you recommend a good tool even a retail product that we can use ?
Thanks in advance 
G.

Comment: This gets asked about 3 times a day. Search and ye will find.

Comment: Apparently a company called Adobe have some PDF offerings that are quite respectable

Comment: guys believe me i have search the web and this site, i wanted a focused answer for converting any printable document and that is a bit more hard to find.

Comment: Given that you just accepted the suggestion to use iTextPDF, you either don't know how to search or didn't spend enough time trying. That and PDFsharp have been given as answers almost *every time* this question was asked.

Comment: we use itextpdf here also, and i like it. i gave accepted because it is a good tool to use, but we are exploring all options due to insufficient time to create our custom tool. thank you cody for your help and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://itextpdf.com/ is one of the pdf creation tool that you can try for

Answer (score 1):

[Aspose](http://www.aspose.com) is not cheap but has great PDF and other document format tools

Answer (score 0):

[GO2PDF](http://www.go2pdf.com/product.html)
may also be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For a tool that is optimised for use on the server, is scalable, robust and with a friendly Web Services API [have a look at this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx).

Doesn't work with 'any printable document', but it gets you pretty far and is adding new formats all the time.